# Routing using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

[router.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpea9.png)I am trying to complete an online test series. I am stuck on one of the exercises where a web app needs to be built. Home Page displays a simple html form for inputs "name" and "age".
When the data is posted, it should route to a new page with path "display" displaying name and age. The modular approach required with App, routers, handlers, server files. Port: 3333. 
Kindly provide a solution.
[server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BPc2.png)

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Comment: Not sure how to pass the data from simple form

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple routes. When the data gets postet, a post route to '/' will handle the data, which you can receive with req.body.

After handling the data you can just redirect like res.redirect('/')

Comment: if (request.method === 'GET') {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.end('Hello, World!');
} else if (request.method === 'POST') {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.end('Success');
}

Answer (score 0):

function startserver(route, handle){

```
function onRequest(request, response){

    var body = '';

    if (request.method === 'GET') {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
            response.end(postHTML); 
        } else if (request.method === 'POST') { 

            request.on('data',function(chunk){
                body += chunk;
                console.log(chunk)
            });

            request.on('end',function(){
                console.log(body)
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                response.end(body);
            })


        }
}; 

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3333);
```

};